# Tarantool sharding - how to search by secondary index?

Tags: caching, nosql, sharding, tarantool

For sharding on tarantool I'am using rocks https://github.com/tarantool/shard and it works perfect for searching by `primary` index.

I have space `events` with `primary` key and `secondary` index.

```
box.schema.create_space('events')
box.space.events:create_index(
    "id", {type = 'primary', parts = {1, 'unsigned'}}
)
box.space.events:create_index(
    "secondary", {type = "tree", unique=true, parts = {2, 'str'}}
)
shard.events:insert{1, "pv.1", 3, 12345671, "uuid1"}
shard.events:insert{2, "pv.2", 3, 12345672, "uuid2"}

-- query by primary index works! and return tuple
shard.events:select{2} 

-- query by secondary index NOT work!
shard.events.index.event_hash:select('pv.2', {iterator = box.index.EQ})
```

My question is:

**What I have to use or what i have to do for query shards by `secondary` index?**

Comment: It does not work on master branch, can you try a 'master-fix-bugs' branch?

Sharing is still experimental in OpenSource version :)